# Как в поле ввода номера задать регулярное выражение для укр. телефона со статическими +380 ....?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Всем привет. Есть простая форма: поле для ввода телефона (для Украины) и кнопка отправки. С помощью паттерна задал регулярное выражение, но не то. Нужно чтобы в поле при наборе номера отображались 4 символа +380.
а дальше уже пользователь вносит остальные цифры?
вот форма:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form"  action="send-tel.php" target="_blank" method="post" name="form">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="000-000-00-00" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" name="telephone" required="required">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button">Перезвоните мне</button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я думаю, Вам нужно воспользоваться маской. Например, [этой](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

HTML:

```
<input class="phone-mask" name="phone" type="text">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.phone-mask').mask('+38-000-000-0000');
});
```

**Update:**

Чтобы всё удовлетворяло Вашим требованиям, вот код, я проверил:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mask.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="phone-mask" name="phone" type="text">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jMaskGlobals = {translation: {
                'n': {pattern: /\d/},
            }
        };
        $('.phone-mask').mask('+380nn-nnn-nnnn').val('+380');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Здесь важно заметить, что замену `0` на число, я меняю в глобальных настройках так, чтобы `n` менялось на число. Тогда введя такую маску, код `+380` будет определяться сам.

P.S. Еще хочу заметить по поводу юзабилити. Если Вы не хотите давать менять эту часть телефона - ее, по моему мнению, лучше вынести за пределы инпута. Или, как минимум, в дизайне жестко намекнуть, что эта часть телефона не меняется (например, тусклым цветом шрифта)

Comment: пожалуйста дополните ваш ответ, примером. Дабы информация хранилась здесь на stackoverflow. Иначе если, что то случится с ресурсом на который Вы ссылаетесь, ваш ответ не будет иметь не какого смысла.

Comment: `type="text"` - зло. На телефоне это открой и посмотри.

Comment: не понял как пользоваться http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").one('focus', function () {
    $(this).val("+380-")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="+380-000-00-00" pattern="^\+380-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" required="required">
    <button type="submit">Перезвоните мне</button>
</form>
```

Comment: уменя много форм на сайте. везде повставлял.. + значения +380 спокойно стираются. их можно как-то зафиксировать?

Comment: @Bogdan 1. Я поменял паттерн на проверку +380 - пусть стирается, напишет снова. 2. Если этот код фиксированный, то почему бы не положить его в span перед инпутом, а запрашивать отдельно 7-значный номер? 3. Можно в input'е подвинуть padding'ом текст и, заменив span на label (и ещё добавив pointer-events:none), положить его частично поверх инпута.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Phone").mask("+380(99) 999-99-99")
```

или

```
$("#Phone").mask("+38(999) 999-99-99")
```