# Поле для ввода номера телефона на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать поле для ввода номера телефона, при нажатии на поле появлялся +, как первый знак, после чего можно было ввести еще 12 чисел, и нельзя писать числа перед плюсом и удалять плюс, код на чистом(ванильном) JS, через .mask нашел ([Как в поле ввода номера задать регулярное выражение для укр. телефона со статическими +380 ....?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5#)), но ради одного кода не хочу подключать библиотеку...

```
<form action="">
        <input type="text" name="tel"  placeholder="Номер телефона" required max="13" id="tel">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну... Валидация формата может быть весьма нетривиальной задачей, так что, возможно, отдельный плагин, вылизанный кучей народа, может быть весьма кстати.

```js
let inp = document.querySelector('#tel');

// Проверяем фокус
inp.addEventListener('focus', _ => {
  // Если там ничего нет или есть, но левое
  if(!/^\+\d*$/.test(inp.value))
    // То вставляем знак плюса как значение
    inp.value = '+';
});

inp.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  // Отменяем ввод не цифр
  if(!/\d/.test(e.key))
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
input:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <!-- Ограничение на длину: maxlength -->
  <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона" required maxlength="13" id="tel">
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает отлично, но есть один нюанс, очень страшно это или нет не знаю)) перед плюсом можно вводить числа...

Comment: в ЕИ не работает, и можна плюс удалить(

Answer (score 2):

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");

inp.onclick = function() {
    inp.value = "+";
}

var old = 0;

inp.onkeydown = function() {
    var curLen = inp.value.length;
    
    if (curLen < old){
      old--;
      return;
      }
    
    if (curLen == 2) 
     inp.value = inp.value + "(";
      
    if (curLen == 6)
     inp.value = inp.value + ")-";
      
     if (curLen == 11)
     inp.value = inp.value + "-"; 
      
     if (curLen == 14)
     inp.value = inp.value + "-";  
      
     if (curLen > 16)
     inp.value = inp.value.substring(0, inp.value.length - 1);
      
     old++;
}
```

```html
<form><input id="inp"></input></form>
```

Comment: можно вводить буквы, и когда быстро вводишь не появляются  символы ( ) -

Comment: и стереть дальше первого дефиса нельзя.

Comment: исправил осталось проверку на цыфру ввести

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var eventCalllback = function(e) {
    var el = e.target,
      clearVal = el.dataset.phoneClear,
      pattern = el.dataset.phonePattern,
      matrix_def = "+7(___) ___-__-__",
      matrix = pattern ? pattern : matrix_def,
      i = 0,
      def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
      val = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (clearVal !== 'false' && e.type === 'blur') {
      if (val.length < matrix.match(/([\_\d])/g).length) {
        e.target.value = '';
        return;
      }
    }
    if (def.length >= val.length) val = def;
    e.target.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
      return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? "" : a
    });
  }
  var phone_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-phone-pattern]');
  for (let elem of phone_inputs) {
    for (let ev of ['input', 'blur', 'focus']) {
      elem.addEventListener(ev, eventCalllback);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input name="phone" data-phone-pattern />
```

Вот простейший вариант.
Подробное описание можно [посмотреть тут](https://webkaa.ru/javascript/maska-nomera-telefona-js).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="telmask" maxlength="12">


const input = document.body.querySelector('.telmask');

  input.addEventListener('keypress', (evt) => {
    if (evt.keyCode < 47 || evt.keyCode > 57) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  })

  input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    if (input.value.length === 0) {
      input.value = '+7';
      input.selectionStart = input.value.length;
    }
  })

  input.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    if (input.selectionStart < 2) {
      input.selectionStart = input.value.length;
    }
    if (evt.key === 'Backspace' && input.value.length <= 2) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  })

  input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    if (input.value === '+7') {
      input.value = '';
    }
  })

  input.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => {
    if (evt.key === 'Backspace' && input.value.length <= 2) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  })
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]